# How to use Asynctask for bitmap?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-asynctask

I'm taking the image from my mp3 files to a **Bitmap[]** but it causes the application to stop a bit and I'm wanting to use Asynctask to make it smoother.

*This is the way I got the bitmap :*

```
  Bitmap[] bm = new Bitmap[mySongs.size()];       
  for (int i = 0; i < mySongs.size(); i++) {
        if (mySongs.size() > 0) {
        u = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(i).toString());
        mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), u);      
        byte[] artBytes = mediaMetadataRetriever.getEmbeddedPicture();  
        if(artBytes != null) {
            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(mediaMetadataRetriever.getEmbeddedPicture());
            bm[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);         
        }  
   }
```

How to put it in Asynctask?

Comment: Just put it in `doInBackground()` of your AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what your implementation would look like:

```
  AsyncTask myAsyncTask = new AsyncTask() {
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
      //ToDo: Do all the work in here and return result as object
      return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
      super.onPostExecute(o);
      //ToDo: Do whatever you want to do with the result in here
    }
  }
```

---

I would suggest creating a static class that extends `AsyncTask` or do not pass any context in here or memory leaks might occur